# cloud 9 seems to work but not showing anything on chrome

Tags: google-chrome, ssh, embedded-linux, cloud9-ide, beagleboneblack

i am using a beaglebone black connected to my computer through the router his adress is 192.168.1.3  i have ssh into him and upgrade the cloud 9 to 0.6-r4.5 and start cloud9 using cloud9 start commande but when i open chrome in my laptop and open 192.168.1.3:3000 it start working and then the name of the tab change to cloud9 but in the inside of the page nothing appear at all just a grey background
did any body solve this before i think that something in my laptop is prohibiting cloud9 from starting

Comment: note i am using 7" LCD CAPE